# Integral on unit disk of a function involving Abs

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The goal is to find with Mathematica that $\int\mathrm{d}^{2}z\log|z-u|^{2}$ is $\pi(|u|^2-1)$ for $|u|\leq 1$ and is $2\pi\log|u|$ for $|u|\geq 1$.

`NIntegrate` confirms this.  `Integrate[r Log[Abs[r Exp[I t] - u]^2], {r,0,1}, {t,0,2Pi}]` is not simplified.  Knowing that there are difficulties because `Abs` is not holomorphic, I replaced the expression with the following locally holomorphic function of r and t.  Without `Assumptions` Mathematica gives a `ConditionalExpression` that is only defined at `u=-I`.  With `Assumptions->0<u<1` one gets a wrong answer that has an extra `Log[u]` term:

```
Integrate[
 r Log[(r Exp[I t] - u) (r Exp[-I t] - u)], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1},
 Assumptions -> {0 < u, u < 1}]
```

gives `Pi (-1 + u^2 + Log[u])`.  This conflicts with the same integral computed for `u=1/2`, for which `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` give `-3Pi/4` and its numerical approximation.

How should I compute the integral indicated at the top of my question?  What causes the extra `Log[u]` term?  (Probably a bad choice of branch cut.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`In[17]:= ComplexExpand[(r Exp[I t] - u) (r Exp[-I t] - u)]`

`Out[17]= u^2 - 2 r u Cos[t] + r^2 Cos[t]^2 + r^2 Sin[t]^2`

`In[18]:= Simplify[%]`

`Out[18]= r^2 + u^2 - 2 r u Cos[t]`

`In[16]:= Integrate[
 r Log[r^2 + u^2 - 2 r u Cos[t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {0 < u, u < 1}]`

`Out[16]= \[Pi] (-1 + u^2)`

`In[19]:= Integrate[
 r Log[r^2 + u^2 - 2 r u Cos[t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {u > 1}]`

`Out[19]= 2 \[Pi] Log[u]`

Comment: Ah, so making the integrand into an expression involving only real quantities before integrating with appropriate assumptions.  Thanks!